# Connecting a SAS server drive with SATA USB cable + Converter

Tags: sata, sas

I'd like to connect a SAS drive (ST3600057SS) to my computer via a USB SATA cable combined with a [SAS to SATA](http://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-18in-SATA-Cable-Power/dp/B000V72AQ4) converter.

This doesn't work and I would like to know why and if there's any way around it.

Answer (score 5):

That has only changed the physical layer (the form factor of the connector).

The signalling protocol is still SAS which is unsupported by your controller.

Comment: Is there any way to make the connection

Comment: Yep! Buy a SAS controller. You can find low-end ones like the IBM M1015 (LSI 9211-based) for dirt cheap. Then get a breakout cable such as http://ca.startech.com/Cables/Drive/SAS/50cm-Internal-Serial-Attached-SCSI-Mini-SAS-Cable-SFF8087-to-4x-FF8482~SAS808782P50

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because your computer doesn't support SAS drives. And that isn't a USB cable...